# Yii2 RestFull Api

Tags: yii2, rest

Для одного проекта надо создать api. Проект на Yii2, поэтому смотрю эту [статью](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start)

Как я понял, сам контроллер знает что делать, когда видит тип запроса. Но что делать, если мне надо не просто создать пользователя, а еще сделать перед этим кое какие действия?

Comment: В данной статье лишь пример организации RESTful Api, подойдет он или нет - решать вам. Если нужен простой CRUD, то смело берите `ActiveController`. В иных случаях вам поможет `yii\rest\Controller`, в котором вы можете организовать свою логику как и в обычных контроллерах.

Comment: спасибо, на данный момент как раз сделал через `yii\rest\Controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данной статье лишь пример организации RESTful Api, подойдет он или нет - решать вам. Если нужен простой CRUD, то смело берите `ActiveController`. В иных случаях вам поможет `yii\rest\Controller`, в котором вы можете организовать свою логику как и в обычных контроллерах.